# How do you set a selected <option> based on runtime criteria

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This code works great:

```
<select v-model="selected_service">
  <option>- select one -</option>
  <option v-for="service in services">{{ service }}</option>
</select>
```

But how do I make one of the `<option>` tags inside the `v-for` loop be `selected`, based on variables that are not known until runtime?

*edit*

The critera for selection is a field on the service object that may or may not be defined.

Comment: Just set selected_service. The correct option will be automatically selected. You also need `<option v-for="service in services" :value="service">{{service}}</option>`.

Comment: @Bert  That did the trick!  If you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept/upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Bert indicated, you can bind the value of your `<option>`s with `v-bind:value="NEWVALUE"` or the [shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand) `:value="NEWVALUE"`. In your case:
`<option :value="service">`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    services: [
      'service 1',
      'service 2',
      'service 3'
    ],
    selected_service: 'service 2'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected_service">
    <option>- select one -</option>
    <option v-for="service in services" :value="service">{{service}}</option>
  </select>
  <div>Selected service: {{selected_service}}</div>
</div>
```